# Can every nontrivial loop be moved to any nontrivial loop in $RP^2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider $X = RP^2$.

Suppose I have two loops $a,b: [0,1] \to X$ which are injective (apart from $a(0) = a(1)$, $b(0) = b(1)$) and both are nontrivial in $\pi (X)$ (And so are the same).

When is there a homeomorphism $F: X \to X$ s.t $F \cdot a  = b$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think so.

Let $\alpha$ be your loop. If you consider it as a path it lifts to a path $\alpha_1$
in $S^2$ where we are lifting via the projection $\pi:S^2\to RP^2$.
As $\alpha$ is not homotopically
trivial, the endpoints of $\alpha_1$ are antipodal. Let
$\alpha_2$ be the antipodal image of $\alpha_1$. It only meets $\alpha_1$
at its endpoints. We can stick them together to form a simple loop $\beta$.
By the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem, $\beta$ separates $S^2$ into two regions,
$U$ and $V$ say, and $U\cup\beta$ is homeomorphic to the closed
northern hemisphere of $S^2$. We can ensure this homeomorphism preserves
antipodality as a map from $\beta$ to the equator. Extend the homeomorphism to
$S^2$ by preserving antipodality. This descends to a homeomorphism on $RP^2$
sending your loop to a standard one.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't sure Jordan-Schoenflies theorem is that powerful (I though it's only capable to say there are two connected components)

Comment: The Jordan curve theorem says there are two components. The Schoenflies theorem (harder) ensures that the curve can be "straightened out".